# ebpf tc failed calling bpf_csum_diff a second time

Tags: c, linux-kernel, ebpf, bpf

I was trying to modify both the source ip and dest ip using tc after reading [this interesting blog](http://arthurchiao.art/blog/cracking-k8s-node-proxy/#7-implementation-4-proxy-via-tc-level-ebpf).

Here is the code:

```c
__section("egress")
int tc_egress(struct __sk_buff *skb)
{
    const __be32 cluster_ip = SRC_IP_ADDR;
    const __be32 pod_ip = IBP_IP_ADDR;
    const __be32 loc_ip = LOC_IP_ADDR;
    const int l3_off = ETH_HLEN;    // IP header offset
    const int l4_off = l3_off + 20; // TCP header offset: l3_off + sizeof(struct iphdr)
    __be32 sum;                     // IP checksum
    void *data = (void *)(long)skb->data;
    void *data_end = (void *)(long)skb->data_end;
    if (data_end < data + l4_off) { // not our packet
        return TC_ACT_OK;
    }
    struct iphdr *ip4 = (struct iphdr *)(data + l3_off);
    if (ip4->daddr != cluster_ip || ip4->protocol != IPPROTO_TCP /* || tcp->dport == 80 */) {
        return TC_ACT_OK;
    }
    if (data_end < data + l4_off + sizeof(struct tcphdr)) { // have verifier give a enough range
        return TC_ACT_OK;
    }
    struct tcphdr *tcph = (struct tcphdr *)(data + l4_off);
    if (bpf_ntohs(tcph->dest) != 9080) {
        return TC_ACT_OK;
    }
    // DNAT: cluster_ip -> pod_ip, then update L3 and L4 checksum
    sum = csum_diff((void *)&ip4->daddr, 4, (void *)&pod_ip, 4, 0);
    skb_store_bytes(skb, l3_off + offsetof(struct iphdr, daddr), (void *)&pod_ip, 4, 0);
    l3_csum_replace(skb, l3_off + offsetof(struct iphdr, check), 0, sum, 0);
    l4_csum_replace(skb, l4_off + offsetof(struct tcphdr, check), 0, sum, BPF_F_PSEUDO_HDR);

    // modify source ip then update l3 and l4 checksum
    sum = csum_diff((void *)&ip4->saddr, 4, (void *)&loc_ip, 4, 0);
    skb_store_bytes(skb, l3_off + offsetof(struct iphdr, saddr), (void *)&loc_ip, 4, 0);
    l3_csum_replace(skb, l3_off + offsetof(struct iphdr, check), 0, sum, 0);
    l4_csum_replace(skb, l4_off + offsetof(struct tcphdr, check), 0, sum, BPF_F_PSEUDO_HDR);

    return redirect(19, 0);
}
```

The blog author's original code worked fine, but mine, with a second `csum_diff` and its following, could not be loaded due to the verifier.

Here is the error message during loading:

```
libbpf: -- BEGIN DUMP LOG ---
libbpf: 
0: R1=ctx(off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0 
0: (bf) r6 = r1                       ; R1=ctx(off=0,imm=0) R6_w=ctx(off=0,imm=0)
1: (b7) r1 = 139192586                ; R1_w=139192586 
2: (63) *(u32 *)(r10 -4) = r1         ; R1_w=139192586 R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm????
3: (b7) r1 = 335587520                ; R1_w=335587520 
4: (63) *(u32 *)(r10 -8) = r1         ; R1_w=335587520 R10=fp0 fp-8=335587520 
5: (b7) r0 = 0                        ; R0_w=0 
6: (61) r1 = *(u32 *)(r6 +80)         ; R1_w=pkt_end(off=0,imm=0) R6_w=ctx(off=0,imm=0)
7: (61) r7 = *(u32 *)(r6 +76)         ; R6_w=ctx(off=0,imm=0) R7_w=pkt(off=0,r=0,imm=0)
8: (bf) r2 = r7                       ; R2_w=pkt(off=0,r=0,imm=0) R7_w=pkt(off=0,r=0,imm=0)
9: (07) r2 += 34                      ; R2_w=pkt(off=34,r=0,imm=0) 
10: (2d) if r2 > r1 goto pc+68        ; R1_w=pkt_end(off=0,imm=0) R2_w=pkt(off=34,r=34,imm=0)
11: (61) r2 = *(u32 *)(r7 +30)        ; R2_w=scalar(umax=4294967295,var_off=(0x0; 0xffffffff)) R7_w=pkt(off=0,r=34,imm=0) 
12: (55) if r2 != 0x100007f goto pc+66        ; R2_w=16777343 
13: (71) r2 = *(u8 *)(r7 +23)         ; R2=scalar(umax=255,var_off=(0x0; 0xff)) R7=pkt(off=0,r=34,imm=0) 
14: (55) if r2 != 0x6 goto pc+64      ; R2=6 
15: (bf) r2 = r7                      ; R2_w=pkt(off=0,r=34,imm=0) R7=pkt(off=0,r=34,imm=0)
16: (07) r2 += 54                     ; R2_w=pkt(off=54,r=34,imm=0) 
17: (2d) if r2 > r1 goto pc+61        ; R1=pkt_end(off=0,imm=0) R2_w=pkt(off=54,r=54,imm=0)
18: (69) r1 = *(u16 *)(r7 +36)        ; R1_w=scalar(umax=65535,var_off=(0x0; 0xffff)) R7=pkt(off=0,r=54,imm= 0) 
19: (55) if r1 != 0x7823 goto pc+59   ; R1_w=30755 
20: (bf) r1 = r7                      ; R1_w=pkt(off=0,r=54,imm=0) R7=pkt(off=0,r=54,imm=0)
21: (07) r1 += 30                     ; R1_w=pkt(off=30,r=54,imm=0) 
22: (07) r7 += 26                     ; R7_w=pkt(off=26,r=54,imm=0) 
23: (bf) r9 = r10                     ; R9_w=fp0 R10=fp0 
24: (07) r9 += -4                     ; R9_w=fp-4 
25: (b7) r2 = 4                       ; R2_w=4 
26: (bf) r3 = r9                      ; R3_w=fp-4 R9_w=fp-4 
27: (b7) r4 = 4                       ; R4_w=4 
28: (b7) r5 = 0                       ; R5_w=0 
29: (85) call bpf_csum_diff#28        ; R0=scalar() 
30: (bf) r8 = r0                      ; R0=scalar(id=1) R8_w=scalar(id=1) 
31: (bf) r1 = r6                      ; R1_w=ctx(off=0,imm=0) R6=ctx(off=0,imm=0) 
32: (b7) r2 = 30                      ; R2_w=30 
33: (bf) r3 = r9                      ; R3_w=fp-4 R9=fp-4 
34: (b7) r4 = 4                       ; R4_w=4 
35: (b7) r5 = 0                       ; R5_w=0 
36: (85) call bpf_skb_store_bytes#9   ; R0_w=scalar() 
37: (bf) r1 = r6                      ; R1_w=ctx(off=0,imm=0) R6=ctx(off=0,imm=0) 
38: (b7) r2 = 24                      ; R2_w=24 
39: (b7) r3 = 0                       ; R3_w=0 
40: (bf) r4 = r8                      ; R4_w=scalar(id=1) R8_w=scalar(id=1) 
41: (b7) r5 = 0                       ; R5_w=0 
42: (85) call bpf_l3_csum_replace#10          ; R0=scalar()
43: (bf) r1 = r6                      ; R1_w=ctx(off=0,imm=0) R6=ctx(off=0,imm=0)
44: (b7) r2 = 50                      ; R2_w=50 
45: (b7) r3 = 0                       ; R3_w=0 
46: (bf) r4 = r8                      ; R4_w=scalar(id=1) R8=scalar(id=1) 
47: (b7) r5 = 16                      ; R5_w=16 
48: (85) call bpf_l4_csum_replace#11          ; R0_w=scalar() 
49: (bf) r8 = r10                     ; R8_w=fp0 R10=fp0 
50: (07) r8 += -8                     ; R8_w=fp-8 
51: (bf) r1 = r7                      ; R1_w=scalar(id=2) R7=scalar(id=2) 
52: (b7) r2 = 4                       ; R2_w=4 
53: (bf) r3 = r8                      ; R3_w=fp-8 R8_w=fp-8 
54: (b7) r4 = 4                       ; R4_w=4 
55: (b7) r5 = 0                       ; R5_w=0 
56: (85) call bpf_csum_diff#28 
R1 type=scalar expected=fp, pkt, pkt_meta, map_key, map_value, mem, ringbuf_mem, buf processed 57 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 3 peak_states 3 mark_read 2
```

According to the [BPF Reference Guide](https://docs.cilium.io/en/stable/bpf/architecture/#instruction-set), `R7` is a callee-saved. And its last assignment before line 56 is at line 22, `R7_w=pkt(off=26,r=54,imm=0)`. However, at line 51, when setting the first argument in `R1` for `bpf_csum_diff`, it became a scalar which caused the verification failure at line 56.

Could someone tell me why it came to this, and any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR.** Helpers `skb_store_bytes`, `l3_csum_replace`, and `l4_csum_replace` are known to the verifier as helpers that modify the packet's data. **When such helpers are called, the verifier simply invalidates all packet pointers.**

**Solutions.** You will therefore have to rebuild the packet pointers from the context argument (`skb`). Or you could compute checksum diff in one go, before making all writes to the packet.

---

**Debugging**

By moving the second call to `csum_diff` up by a few lines, we can confirm that a call to `skb_store_bytes` is enough to reproduce the issue.

Most of the static analysis of helper calls happens in function `check_helper_call`. That function [checks](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.5.5/source/kernel/bpf/verifier.c#L9395) if the analyzed helper is one of [those known to modify packet data](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.5.5/source/net/core/filter.c#L7750). If that is the case, it calls `clear_all_pkt_pointers` [just before returning](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.5.5/source/kernel/bpf/verifier.c#L9792).

`clear_all_pkt_pointers` [goes over all packet pointers](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.5.5/source/kernel/bpf/verifier.c#L8596) known to the verifier and clears them. That ends up calling `__mark_reg_unknown`, which simply [marks the register as an unknown scalar](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.5.5/source/kernel/bpf/verifier.c#L2261).

Putting it all together:

```c
static int check_helper_call(struct bpf_verifier_env *env, struct bpf_insn *insn,
             int *insn_idx_p)
{
    [...]
    changes_data = bpf_helper_changes_pkt_data(fn->func);
    [...]
    if (changes_data)
        clear_all_pkt_pointers(env);
    return 0;
}

static void clear_all_pkt_pointers(struct bpf_verifier_env *env)
{
    struct bpf_func_state *state;
    struct bpf_reg_state *reg;

    bpf_for_each_reg_in_vstate(env->cur_state, state, reg, ({
        if (reg_is_pkt_pointer_any(reg) || reg_is_dynptr_slice_pkt(reg))
            mark_reg_invalid(env, reg);
    }));
}

static void __mark_reg_unknown(const struct bpf_verifier_env *env,
                   struct bpf_reg_state *reg)
{
    /*
     * Clear type, off, and union(map_ptr, range) and
     * padding between 'type' and union
     */
    memset(reg, 0, offsetof(struct bpf_reg_state, var_off));
    reg->type = SCALAR_VALUE;
    reg->id = 0;
    reg->ref_obj_id = 0;
    reg->var_off = tnum_unknown;
    reg->frameno = 0;
    reg->precise = !env->bpf_capable;
    __mark_reg_unbounded(reg);
}
```